# Too many API requests are sent when loading ReactJS page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import LogoImg  from '../img/logoimg.png'



function CoronaInfoKoreaApi() {
    const serviceKey = "serviceKey "

    const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
    const [todayInfo, setTodayInfo] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const url = `https://api.corona-19.kr/korea/?serviceKey=${serviceKey}`;
    const url2 = `https://api.corona-19.kr/korea/country/new/?serviceKey=${serviceKey}`
    const apiRequest = async () => {
        try {
          // 요청이 시작 할 때에는 error 와 users 를 초기화하고
          setError(null);
          setTodayInfo(null);
          setInfo(null);
          // loading 상태를 true 로 바꿉니다.
          setLoading(true);
          const response1 = await axios.get(
            url
          );
          const response2 = await axios.get(
            url2
          );
          setTodayInfo(response2.data.korea); // 데이터는 response.data 안에 들어있습니다.
          setInfo(response1.data); // 데이터는 response.data 안에 들어있습니다.
        } catch (e) {
          setError(e);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        apiRequest();
      }, []);
```

The service key can be obtained from `https://api.corona-19.kr/`

I am working on the above code in ReactJS
When entering the web page, the API request is repeated 30 times per second. Where is it repeated?

If the code is long and you need the rest, I will attach it to the link below.
https://github.com/kiss8981/corona-info-react/blob/main/src/api/CoronaInfoKoreaApi.js

Comment: we need to know where and how you call `apiRequest ` ? also consider adding `console.trace` on your method to find call stack and may find your root cause

Comment: Problem is the multiple re-rendering of the CoronaInfoKoreaAPI.

Ensure that multiple re-renders don't happen.

Comment: @Yanis-git It's called in `useEffect`.

Comment: @nirbhaygp Right--the OP is asking *why*.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you provided that would cause the API request to be executed multiple times. Is the `CoronaInfoKoreaApi` component being mounted multiple times?

Comment: After looking at the code, rendering is happening from Home Component, should be implemented either as a PureComponent or shouldComponentUpdate in the Home Class Component be implemented. Functional components get rendered every time

Comment: @nirbhaygp The empty dep array means the effect only runs once on mount and unmount, regardless of how many times or why the component rerenders

Answer (score 1):

```
const apiRequest = async () => {
try {
  const res = await Promise.all([
    axios.get(url),
    axios.get(url2),
    
  ]);
  const data = res.map((res) => res.data);
  console.log(data.flat());
} catch {
  throw Error("Promise failed");
}
```

};